# How to set a max height and allow scrolling with jQueryUI Selectmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I'm trying to use the new [jQueryUI selectmenu](http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/) widget to get custom styling for my `<select>` dropdown and retain full functionality. But it appears to be practically useless for large lists. In its default state when opened, the dropdown items just keep running off the page and there is no scrolling enabled. I find this to be bizarre for a plugin which can supposedly replace the standard HTML `<select>` dropdown menu.

Is there a way to fix this e.g. set a max height on the dropdown items that are shown and enable scrolling? Maybe I missed an API option. I suppose it could be done with some creative CSS?

[Here is a JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mjfnao1L/) showing what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There sure is a way of doing that, and fortunately, it's incredibly simple! :)

You simply need to define a max-height for the `<ul>`:

```
#countries-menu {
    max-height: 100px;
}
```

Note that the `max-height` could instead be applied to `.ui-selectmenu-menu .ui-menu` if you'd like to adjust any select menu in jQuery UI.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mjfnao1L/1/

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I'll give you the tick because you were first to answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the height to a percentage of the viewable height, you can use this code below. This will set it to 90% of the viewable height, which will allow users with larger screens to see more options:

```
#countries-menu {
  max-height: 90vh;
}
```